# proving set theory proving (B' ∩ u) ∩ (A' ∪ φ) = (A ∪ B)'

Tags: set, discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me prove below set 
(B' ∩ u) ∩ (A' ∪ φ) = (A ∪ B)'

please note in (B' ∩ u) this is  (B' ∩ set u)

Comment: Maybe you should visit [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Union of φ with any set will result that set, so `(A' ∪ φ)=A'`
intersection of any set with U set will be, that set, `(B' ∩ u)=B'`

Thus the left side result in `B' ∩ A'` which is Euler representation of right side.

Comment: Is the letter phi used as an alternative empty-set symbol?

Comment: Exactly! It's the empty-set symbol here.

Comment: thanks for reply. but in my question first term (B' ∩ u) , U is not a universal set. it is another set u.

Comment: In this situation, do you have any other property related to u? because there should be one!

Comment: no. do you think this is printing mistake? i am not sure about this.

Comment: Yes! Most probably it is a printing mistake.